# How can I make two divs within the same parent container scroll independently of each other?

Tags: html, css, scrollbar

I am trying to figure out how to get two of my divs to scroll independently of each other. Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dgoetzit/jsmfd1bp/9/) showing what I have so far. As you will notice, when you scroll to the bottom and the top of the ".livebar", it also changes the position of the ".site-page-container".

Here is my html:

```
<div class="container">

<div class="livebar-container">
 <div class="livebar">
  <h1>
  This is the livebar
  </h1>
   <p>
    //content
   </p>
   <br>
   <p>
    //content
   </p>
 </div>
</div>

<header class="site-header">
 <h1>
  This is the header
 </h1>
</header>

<div class="site-page-container">
 <div class="site-page">
  <h1>
   This is the site page
  </h1>
   <p>
    //content
   </p>
   <br>
   <p>
    //content
   </p>
 </div>
</div>

</div>
```

Here is my css:

```
.livebar-container {
    overflow: hidden;
}
.livebar {
    overflow: auto;
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    text-align: center;
    float: left;
    width: 20%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: blue;
}

div.container {
    max-width: 100vw;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;

}

.site-page-container {
    height: 100vh;
    width: 80%;
    float: right;
    margin-top: auto;
    background-color: green;
}

.site-page {
    display: inline-block;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
}

.site-header {
    background-color: purple;
    width: 80%;
    height: auto;
    text-align: center;
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    float: right;
}
```

When you scroll to the bottom and top of the ".site-page-container", it's movement does not affect the position of the ".livebar".

How can I make it so that the ".livebar" div scrolls independently of the ".site-page-container" div and doesn't impact it in any way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is because the scrollbar on the right is actually a parent element scrollbar (which applies to both the divs).

Try giving

```
overflow:hidden
```

to body tag and

```
overflow:scroll
```

to site-page-container class